# HTML not get in node js puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

**Error**

Cannnot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null

I am scraping this [site](https://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html), when I write the below lines in console it gives me the HTML. But when I scrape the HTML from puppeteer it gives me error

```
document.querySelectorAll('#stroke-play-container > .stroke-play-leaderboard > .the-leaderboard.with-rolex > table.leaderboard.leaderboard-table.large')[0].nextSibling;
```

**Code**

```
'use strict';

 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
 function run() {
 return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {


        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless : false
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto("https://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html");

        await page.evaluate(`window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)`);
        await page.waitFor(5000);
    
        let urls = await page.evaluateHandle(() => {
            let results = [];
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            
            var node = document.querySelectorAll('#stroke-play-container > .stroke-play-leaderboard > .the-leaderboard.with-rolex > table.leaderboard.leaderboard-table.large')[0].nextSibling;
           
            if(node){

            var $ = parser.parseFromString(node, 'text/html');
            
          
            return {
                name: $.querySelectorAll('table > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr > td.player-name > div > div.player-name-col').innerText
            };
            }
            else{
                return 'error';
            }

        })
        browser.close();
        return resolve(urls);
    } catch (e) {
        return reject(e);
    }
})
}
 run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Can you use evaluate instead of evaluateHandle and see if that helps?

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: nextSiblings is not working in chromium

Comment: fyi: [ToC](https://www.pgatour.com/company/tos.html) 7. conduct. (b) You shall not use or permit or facilitate others to use PGATOUR.com by automated electronic processes, robots, spiders, scrapers, webcrawlers, or other computer programs that monitor, copy or download data or other content found on or accessed through PGATOUR.com, including without limitation real time scoring, video, audio, statistics, polling, or data content, whether current or archival.

Comment: @Lawrence - That page is public and has no ToS. People are not bound to contracts that they didn't agree to believe it or not.

Comment: @pguardiario Whether its law or not, one must still have a conversation with their inner self whether scaping a public site which has tos which specifically say don't, is truly worth it in the long run. I just helping out the fellow code monkey.

Comment: Im sure it will be ok said the VPN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
let names = await page.evaluate(() => {
  let css = '.the-leaderboard.with-rolex > table.leaderboard.leaderboard-table.large + div div.player-name-col'
  let divs = [...document.querySelectorAll(css)]
  return divs.map(div => div.innerText)
})
```

I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish with DOMParser, you shouldn't ever need to use that.

Comment: how I get the next siblings. **table.leaderboard.leaderboard-table.large** after this selector only first div selected. I wanted to get all siblings after this selector **table.leaderboard.leaderboard-table.large**  [image](https://ibb.co/yfY4Twc)

Comment: For all siblings replace + with ~

Comment: excellent (Y). how I learn about these symbols (+, ~) in scraping

Comment: That's just css, there's an official spec if you google for it.

Comment: how I apply loop in siblings row and store in object. because it gives error [image](https://ibb.co/Z1dWjjJ)

Comment: I would give up on DOMParser and use the regular DOM

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments, please be mindful of the Terms of Service of pgatours.com, which do not allow for scraping, crawling etc.
The below solution is only intended to illustrate how to solve the generic technical point behind your question.

I think this might be due to the default viewport size Puppeteer is using. The website is hiding the content you are looking for on smaller resolutions, hence the problem.

What made this work for me was specifying the viewport size explicitly, like so:

```
page.setViewport({ width: 1200, height: 1000 })
```

So your code would become:

```
'use strict';

 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
 function run() {
 return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {


        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless : false
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        page.setViewport({ width: 1200, height: 1000 })


        await page.goto("https://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html");

        await page.evaluate(`window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)`);
        await page.waitFor(5000);
    
        let urls = await page.evaluateHandle(() => {
            let results = [];
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            
            var node = document.querySelectorAll('#stroke-play-container > .stroke-play-leaderboard > .the-leaderboard.with-rolex > table.leaderboard.leaderboard-table.large')[0].nextSibling;
           
            if(node){

            var $ = parser.parseFromString(node, 'text/html');
            
          
            return {
                name: $.querySelectorAll('table > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr > td.player-name > div > div.player-name-col').innerText
            };
            }
            else{
                return 'error';
            }

        })
        browser.close();
        return resolve(urls);
    } catch (e) {
        return reject(e);
    }
})
}
run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, querySelector working in chrome. puppeteer launch chromium if I write the same query selector in chromium it gives the same error "Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of undefined"

Comment: page.setViewportSize did not help

Comment: @Adam my mistake. please try setViewport instead of setViewportSize (that is Playwright syntax)